# Fix a header to the top of a container with overflow: auto;

Tags: html, css

I have some content inside an `overflow: auto;` container:

https://jsfiddle.net/h4y37qwu/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">

</div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
.content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}
```

I try to fix the `.header` block to the top of the `.container` so it was fixed when you scroll. However, it doesn't work with `position: absolute;` Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use `position: absolute;` you can use jquery and the scroll function to offset the top each time you scroll.

see https://jsfiddle.net/rvkh3v4n/

```
$('.container').scroll(function() { 
  $('.header').offset({ top: 8 });
});
```

Comment: That's the best answer, because it keeps the header inside the container with horizontal overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the

```
position:fixed.
```

Here is what you need

```
.header {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
position: fixed;
```

After you do this you have to adjust margins for header according to the container:

```
.header {
  width: 682px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10; left: 10;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4y37qwu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I made a few changes :

no more `position: absolute;`

`overflow: auto` on your .content element

https://jsfiddle.net/h4y37qwu/2/